# Como puedo recuperar el objeto de mi base de datos en Firebase si no se a que nodo pertenece?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Tengo una base de datos en Firebase de productos. Tengo los siquientes nodos:

```
+ Vinos
  "5000" {}
  "5001" {}

+ Quesos
  "6000":{}
  "6001"{}
```

en mi componente solo tengo el codigo y necesito recuperarlo pero no se a que nodo pertenece, tendria que buscar en todos ellos?

mi base de datos es parecido a esto:
Empresa
 - Vinos
   - 5000
      precio: 32.90
      dproducto: Frasca 500ml.
      envase: Vidrio
   - 5001
      precio: 20.05
      dproducto: Frasca 100ml
      envase: Vidrio
 - Quesos
   -6000
      precio: 19.90
      dproducto: Queso añejo
      envase:""

si yo en mi componente tengo el codigo 5000 por ejemplo y quisiera buscarlo para obtener los datos, no se el nodo al que pertenece, osea no puedo poner db.ref('Vinos') o db.ref('Quesos'). como puedo hacerlo? Recorrer todos los nodos y buscarlo????

Comment: Podrias mostrar un ejemplo mas completo de como se ve tu base de datos en firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Sería bueno saber si es database o firestore, en el caso de database lo que puedes hacer es:

```
db.ref('Vinos').equalTo('5000');
```

o quesos, en el caso de firestore:

```
db.collection('Vinos', ref => ref.where ('miValor', '==', '5000'));
```

Espero que sea de ayuda